# Standardize such that mean=1?

Tags: standardization

I am interested in standardizing my data before putting it through a NNMF code, but this prohibits negative values.

Is it possible to standardize data such that the mean=1 and standard deviation=1, contrary to the usual mean=0? If so, how would the general formula look?

Comment: Couldn't you simply do your regular standardization to a mean zero variance one distribution, then simply add one to every data point?

Comment: @tchainzzz That's a good suggestion.  Note, however, that except in special cases (where there are just two distinct values with equal frequencies), there will still be negative values in the transformed dataset, no matter what one does.